# Android Device Manager not opening on MAC

Tags: android-studio

I installed Android studio.

```
 Mac version - 10.12.6
```

In browser it says below

```
 java version - Version 8 Update 144
```

For java version In terminal when I run the command it says below

```
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-468-11M4833)
```

Than I did

```
  export PATH="/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin:$PATH"
```

So it shows

```
 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
```

When I am trying to open Android Device monitor it gives me below error

---

```
!SESSION 2017-08-28 20:42:02.978 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_65
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/arshad/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -data @noDefault -keyring /Users/arshad/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-08-28 20:42:03.752
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-08-28 20:42:03.764
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.jasper.glassfish_2.2.2.v201205150955.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-08-28 20:42:03.765
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.lucene.core_2.9.1.v201101211721.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-08-28 20:42:03.789
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.base_3.6.101.v201302041200.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-08-28 20:42:03.790
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.ui_3.5.201.v20130108-092756.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-08-28 20:42:03.790
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.webapp_3.6.101.v20130116-182509.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-08-28 20:42:03.791
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.jetty.server_8.1.3.v20120522.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-08-28 20:42:03.793
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.platform.doc.user_4.2.2.v20130121-200410.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-08-28 20:42:03.795
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.team.core_3.6.100.v20120524-0627.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-08-28 20:42:03.795
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.team.ui_3.6.201.v20130125-135424.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-08-28 20:42:03.796
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets_3.4.200.v20120521-2344.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-08-28 20:42:03.797
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.ui.intro_3.4.200.v20120521-2344.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.286
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor (5).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor.MonitorPlugin for bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor is invalid
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1212)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/prefs/AndroidLocation$AndroidLocationException : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClassHoldingLock(ClasspathManager.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:614)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor.MonitorPlugin.<clinit>(MonitorPlugin.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:167)
    ... 33 more
Root exception:
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/prefs/AndroidLocation$AndroidLocationException : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClassHoldingLock(ClasspathManager.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:614)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor.MonitorPlugin.<clinit>(MonitorPlugin.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1212)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.403
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.403
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jetty.security_8.1.3.v20120522.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.security 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.403
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.security 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.403
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.403
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal_3.2.600.v20120912-155524/ was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.403
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.intro_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.403
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_8.1.3.v20120522.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.403
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.session_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.403
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.403
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.404
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.404
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.404
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_3.0.1.v20121109-203239.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.404
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.404
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.404
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.404
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.404
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.session_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.404
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.404
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.apache.lucene.analysis_2.9.1.v201101211721.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene.analysis 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.404
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.lucene.core_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.404
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper_1.0.400.v20120912-130548.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.404
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.apache.jasper.servlet_[0.0.0,6.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.404
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.404
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.2.v201302041200/ was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.platform 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.404
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4))(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.platform 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.404
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.intro_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.404
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry_1.0.300.v20120912-130548.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.404
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.404
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.apache.lucene_2.9.1.v201101211721.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.404
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.lucene.core_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.404
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_3.7.0.v20120523-1543.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.404
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.team.ui_[3.4.100,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.404
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.team.core_[3.4.100,4.0.0).

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.433
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.433
!MESSAGE Bundle org.apache.lucene_2.9.1.v201101211721 [25] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.433
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.lucene.core_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.433
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.analysis_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.433
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.highlighter_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.433
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.memory_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.433
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.queries_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.434
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.snowball_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.434
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.spellchecker_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.434
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.misc_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.434
!MESSAGE Bundle org.apache.lucene.analysis_2.9.1.v201101211721 [26] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene.analysis 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.434
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.lucene.core_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.434
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_3.0.1.v20121109-203239 [89] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.434
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.434
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.434
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.434
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.434
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.session_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.434
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.434
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.434
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper_1.0.400.v20120912-130548 [92] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.434
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.apache.jasper.servlet_[0.0.0,6.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.434
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.434
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry_1.0.300.v20120912-130548 [93] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.434
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.434
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.434
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.jetty.security_8.1.3.v20120522 [136] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.security 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.434
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.security 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.434
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.434
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_8.1.3.v20120522 [137] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.434
!MESSAGE Missing optionally imported package org.eclipse.jetty.jmx_8.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.434
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.security_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.434
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.434
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.434
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.434
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.session_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.434
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.434
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_3.7.0.v20120523-1543 [145] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.434
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.team.core_[3.4.100,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.435
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.team.ui_[3.4.100,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.435
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.platform_4.2.2.v201302041200 [148] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.platform 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.435
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.intro_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.platform 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.435
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.platform 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.435
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4))(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.435
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.search_3.8.0.v20120523-1540 [150] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.search 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.435
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.435
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal_3.2.600.v20120912-155524 [162] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.435
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.intro_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.435
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources_3.4.400.v20120705-114010 [164] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources 2 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.435
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_[3.5.0,4.0.0).

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-08-28 20:42:04.436
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor.MonitorApplication.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNv8F.png
```

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: Java Version 8 Update 144

Comment: try using java 7 and see if this fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by deleting Java 9.

On a mac I ran this

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane
sudo rm -rf /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
```